# Angular2 contribution development environment gulp build failing on windows

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

As mentioned in ng-contrib website http://www.ng-contrib.org/program/setting-up#build , gulp build is failing. I am navigating to node_modules/.bin and running the command **gulp build** on windows. Attached screenshot.Can anyone help me with setting up angular2 development environment for contribution.

My node version - v5.12.0
npm version - v3.8.6

[image]